# SOQL: Comparing two custom relationship fields in a nested query

Tags: soql, relationships, nested

I think I may be hitting some sort of SOQL limitation in the WHERE clause. I am trying to return fields from two parent objects, after comparing two date fields on both Objects.

The goal is to have a list of contacts with associated opportunity fields where the opportunity date field is equal to some contact field.

> NOTE: We have a custom junction between Opportunity and Contact named "Opportunity_Contact__c" due to the limits on the standard OCR sObj.

Specifically:

```
SELECT NAME, Con_Custom_Date__c,
  (SELECT Opportunity__r.Name FROM Opportunity_Contacts__r 
   WHERE Contact__r.Con_Custom_Date__c = Opportunity__r.Opp_Custom_Date__c)
FROM Contact
```

This returns a parsing error. However, if I try switching the query to something like:

```
SELECT NAME, Con_Custom_Date__c,
  (SELECT Opportunity__r.Name FROM Opportunity_Contacts__r 
   WHERE Contact__r.Con_Custom_Date__c = TODAY and Opportunity__r.Opp_Custom_Date__c = TODAY)
FROM Contact
```

This works. So the date fields are working and I am able to use them in the WHERE clause. However, when I compare one field directly to the other, I get a parsing error..

Why would

```
WHERE Contact__r.Con_Custom_Date__c = TODAY and Opportunity__r.Opp_Custom_Date__c = TODAY
```

work while

```
WHERE Contact__r.Con_Custom_Date__c = Opportunity__r.Opp_Custom_Date__c
```

triggers a parsing error?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that Reports now can filter on comparing two fields.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ahh, Salesforce doesn't allow direct field to field comparisons in a query. Source:

> ## [Field to field comparison in WHERE clause of SOQL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187460&type=1)
>
> #### Knowledge Article Number
>
> 000187460
>
> #### Description
>
> I want to execute a query by comparing two fields of the same object in WHERE clause, but I am not able to use a field in
>   the right hand side of a condition in a WHERE clause:
>
> ```
>  List<user> users = [SELECT Id,name FROM User WHERE (FirstName != Lastname)];
> ```
>
> The above query returns: "System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'Lastname' "
>
> #### Resolution
>
> Salesforce does not allow direct field to field comparison in SOQL query.
>
> To achieve this you may create a formula field that will compare
>   fields and return a value (like true or false) which you may use in a
>   WHERE clause.
>
> So for the above query, you could create a formula field on User
>   object with return type Checkbox e.g. NameCompare, with the formula
>
> ```
> User.FirstName != User.LastName
> ```
>
> Now our query will be:
>
> ```
> List<User> Users = [SELECT id, name FROM User WHERE NameCompare = TRUE];
> ```
>
> Following idea has been posted on Ideaexchange portal for allowing field-to-field comparison in SOQL: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHAAA0